# Roslyn C#6 ?. operator compilation looks messy in generic types

Tags: roslyn, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

Lets consider the following class definition:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T t;
    public bool? c1(T obj) => obj?.Equals(null);
    public bool? c2() => t?.Equals(null);
}
```

After all, some notes:

- `MyClass<T>` do not impose any constraints about `T` type - so, `T` could be a `class` or a `struct`;
- `c2() == c1(t)` MUST BE always true.
- Im using the http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/ site to compile some code snippets and see what Roslyn emmits.

Now, lets analyze how Roslyn compiles `MyClass<T>`:

**1.)** `c1(T)` case:

How expected, after verifying the generated code by Roslyn compiler, we can see the following:

```
public bool? c1(T obj)
{
    return obj != null ? new bool?(obj.Equals(null)) : null;
}
```

**2.)** `c2()` case:

What I expected was the same code as c1(T). But, what I see is:

```
public unsafe bool? c2()
{
    T* arg_33_0 = ref this.t;
    T t = default(T);
    bool? arg_43_0;
    if (t == null)
    {
        t = this.t;
        arg_33_0 = ref t;
        if (t == null)
        {
            arg_43_0 = null;
            return arg_43_0;
        }
    }
    arg_43_0 = new bool?(arg_33_0.Equals(null));
    return arg_43_0;
}
```

WOW, why this all unnecessary code is emitted? In release compilation mode, we can see that **C1 has 39 bytes** code size while **C2 method has 68 bytes**. Is this something that could be optimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `c1` CIL code would be wrong for the `c2` case.

In the `c1` version, `Equals` gets called on a copy of `obj`. In the `c2` version, extra care must be taken to call `Equals` on `t`, not a copy of `t`. That's because `T` could be a value type that has overridden `Equals` to modify its own instance data. Since you're calling `Equals` on `t`, the modification should be visible in `t`.

The optimisation is possible for `c1` *only* because there's no way for anyone to inspect `obj` after the method has returned, so it doesn't matter whether it's `obj` or a copy of `obj` that potentially gets modified.

Comment: I think it is not related to overridden methods because a **DoNothing(this object obj)** extension method in place of `Equals` call has the same behaviour.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheusCosta Agreed that the shorter CIL code would be valid in that case. For that, I'd guess that it's not done for simplicity of the compiler combined with the fact that it's rare, and the existing CIL code, while longer, is perfectly valid. Nonetheless, it could be a good suggestion for an improvement on the Roslyn issue tracker.